# ViewModel with mixed fields and lists

Tags: c#, list, linq, viewmodel

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class DayTaskListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
    public bool HasRegistrations { get; set; }
    public bool HasStartedRegistrations { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string WorkTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string StateStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime TodaysDate { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public int YearNumber { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public string SignInUserName { get; set; }

    public string UnitCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Machinery> machineryList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Cleaning> cleaningList { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have this definition of the model to be sent to the view:

```
        var model = (from a in _db.WorkTask.Where(y => y.TaskDate.Date == querytodaysDate.Date && y.IsActive == true && (y.IsPrivateUserName == null || y.IsPrivateUserName == currUserName))
                      join b in _db.WorkTaskLog.Where(x => (x.UserName == currUserName || x.UserName == null) && x.IsActive == true && x.StateStatusId < 4) on a.Id equals b.WorkTaskId into joinedT
                      from c in joinedT.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new DayTaskListViewModel
                      {
                          Id = a.Id,
                          DateFormatted = a.DateFormatted,
                          HasRegistrations = a.HasRegistrations,
                          HasStartedRegistrations = a.HasStartedRegistrations,
                          ItemName = a.ItemName,
                          WorkTypeName = a.WorkTypeName,
                          Description = a.Description,
                          IsActive = c.IsActive ? c.IsActive : false,
                          UserName = c.UserName ?? String.Empty,
                          StateStatus = c.StateStatus ?? "Klar",
                          WeekNumber = (int)currWeekNo,
                          YearNumber = (int)currYearNo,
                          Msg = "",
                          TodaysDate = (DateTime)todaysDate,
                          SignInUserName = currUserName,
                          LocationName = a.LocationName,
                          UnitCode = a.UnitCode,
                          //machineryList = _db.Machinery.ToList(),
                          //cleaningList = _db.Cleaning.ToList(),
                      }).ToList();
```

My problem is the following lines in the definition:
//machineryList = _db.Machinery.ToList(),
//cleaningList = _db.Cleaning.ToList(),

Everything works as expected, but as soon as I enable those 2 lines it breaks with null errors.
VS can compile, but it breaks runtime.

I think I see the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
I want ALL fields in the ViewModel EXCEPT the 2 mentioned lines to be a list, and then the 2 lines to be separate lists independent of the majority.
I have tried all combinations of moving those lines around, but then VS complains.

An example from another controller is this:

```
            DriveListViewModel model = new DriveListViewModel()
            {
                Drive = await _db.Drive
                    .Where(m => m.StatusId == 5 || m.StatusId == 1010 || m.StatusId == 1012)
                    .Where(m => m.LoadingComplete == null)
                    .Where(m => !m.UnitCode.Contains(excludeString))
                    .Include(s => s.DriveStatus)
                    .Include(d => d.Location)
                    .Include(f => f.Item)
                    .GroupBy(m => m.RegistrationNumber)
                    .Select(m => m.FirstOrDefault())
                    .OrderBy(m => m.DriverToLoad)
                    .ToListAsync(),
                machineryList = await _db.Machinery.ToListAsync(),
                cleaningList = await _db.Cleaning.ToListAsync(),
            };
```

This works perfectly, but the former model definition as more complex, so basically, I need something similar to the latter example separating the 2 lists from the other properties in the ViewModel.
Maybe this is VERY simple - however I'm struggling with it...

Anyone see the solution to this?

Comment: So... why not just set those two properties after the query? Do the `Select`, then `var machineryList = await _db.Machinery.ToListAsync(); var cleaningList = await _db.Cleaning.ToListAsync(); model.ForEach(m => { m.machineryList  = machineryList; m.cleaningList = cleaningList; });`

Comment: Hi Heretic. I actually got away with your suggestion!  Thanks a lot, it works for now and I can proceed. Thanks a lot. Your and Serge ROCKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you model is a list with so many includes.

I guess you really need this ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
  public  List<DayTaskListViewModel> DayTaskListViewModelList {get; set;}
  public List<Machinery> MachineryList {get; set;}
  public List<Cleaning>   CleaningList {get; set;}
}
```

code

```
 var dayTaskListViewModel= (from ....
 .....
  select new DayTaskListViewModel
  {
    Id = a.Id,
   .......
                   
  }).ToList();  // or ToListAsync too?

var model = new ViewModel
{
   DayTaskListViewModel = dayTaskListViewModel,
   MachineryList = _db.Machinery.ToList(),
   CleaningList = _db.Cleaning.ToList()
}

   // or if you can or prefer , use async
 MachineryList =  await _db.Machinery.ToListAsync(),
  CleaningList = await _db.Cleaning.ToListAsync(),
```

Comment: Hi Serge. Ah, so I can wrap a ViewModel into another ViewModel thus separating the lists as you show?

Comment: Yes, it is more clear or you can use a it is. See my updated answer.

Comment: @RenéWester Sorry it was a mistake. It would be nice if you post a view where you use this model. You don't need to post all properties, just a couple of each kind

Comment: I got away using Heritic Monkeys solution, but yours are definitely also worth trying. You and Heretic ROCKS!  Thanks a lot to both of you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snip of the view:

Top:

```
@model List<Day.Models.ViewModels.DayTaskListViewModel>
@using Day.Extensions
```

Looping through all properties:

```
if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<input name="description" class="form-input" id="description" type="text" value="@item.Description">
    ..Several input fields...
    }
}
```

Works fine.

Then I need to include select fields using the machineryList from the ViewModel:

```
<select name="machinery" asp-items="@Model.machineryList.ToSelectListItem((int)defaultMachinery)"></select>
```